# Как проверить производительность приложения FastCGI?

Tags: fastcgi

Приложение доступно по адресу localhost:80. Стандартные средства вроде curl или C# HttpClient до него достучаться не могут. В браузере прекрасно работает. Как проверить количество запросов в секунду, обрабатываемых приложением?

Comment: Э? Как это браузер может, а curl не может?

Comment: Потому что не HTTP.

Comment: У вас браузер работает не по http?